Serilog don't write to DB in IExceptionHandler (.NET 8)
I want to create a global error handler for .NET Core 8.
Here's the code:
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> _logger;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        
        //work in file, console and MSSQL-Db
        _logger.LogInformation("1-ExceptionHandlingMiddleware");
    }

    public ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext,
        Exception exception,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //work in file, console but not in  MSSQL-Db!!
        _logger.LogInformation("2-ExceptionHandlingMiddleware");
        
        return ValueTask.FromResult(false);
    }
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

app.UseExceptionHandler();

The Serilog logger is configured to write logs to file, console, and SQL Server database. It works fine in various parts of the application, and the handler is properly invoked and logged in the constructor. However, logging to the database doesn't work in the TryHandleAsync method, although it works in file and console logging. Logging to the database works fine in other parts of the application, but not at this particular location. Any ideas?

Please post your Serilog and logging configuration.

var sinkOpts = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions();
sinkOpts.TableName = "_GlobalErrorLog";
sinkOpts.AutoCreateSqlTable = true;

var columnOpts = new ColumnOptions();
columnOpts.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent);
columnOpts.LogEvent.DataLength = 4000;  

I found the error. My code first:
columnOpts.LogEvent.DataLength = 2000;  

I changed it just for fun to the maximum length of 4000:
columnOpts.LogEvent.DataLength = 4000;  

works.
